# Missing glyphs with urxvt-unicode

Tags: arch-linux, unicode, rxvt

I cannot display some special characters in my `urxvt-unicode` terminal emulator on Arch Linux.

My setup:

```
$ cat ~/.Xresources
URxvt.font: xft:Meslo\ LG\ S\ DZ\ for\ Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline:size=9, \
        xft:Pomodoro, \
        xft:FontAwesome, \
        xft:icomoon, \
        xft:octicons

URxvt.scrollBar: false

#include ".Xresources.d/Xresources.dark"


$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

All the fonts are installed and work in other applications (for example my `lemonbar`), only with `urxvt` I get those typical fallback empty boxes. I also tried different fonts, font sizes and font letterspace. Has someone any other hint for me? In particular I need some special characters included in the fallback fonts defined in my `.Xresources`, for example the Linux logo U+F612.

Answer (score 2):

The other applications are using additional fallback fonts which you could discover by tracing them, e.g., using `strace` and looking for `open` calls.

Comment: This really solved the problem for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to lower the size of the fail-over symbol fonts to size 6 or even 5 like:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Meslo\ LG\ S\ DZ\ for\ Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline:size=9, \
            xft:Pomodoro:size=6, \
            xft:FontAwesome:size=6, \
            xft:icomoon:size=6, \
            xft:octicons:size=6
```